# Thing(of T as iConvertible) : possibilities to convert into T? aka using T as expression

Tags: vb.net, casting

I'm trying to make a finction that converts a variable of any convertible type to another type, say string & double, double & integer and so on. (obviously this is a dumbed down version of the truth)

My try :

```
Public Function CasterTheGhost(Of S As IConvertible, T As IConvertible)(ByRef Source As T) As S
    return Source.ToType(S, Nothing)
End Sub
```

S is a type, and ToType takes a type... but compiler tells that a type cannot be used as an expression, which makes no sense to me...

The answer is probably very simple... I just couldn't find it on google :-(

Comment: Well, you can't start with `Function` and end with `End Sub` for starters.

Comment: @Enigmativity : yes sorry I "dumbed down" the code here and forgot this one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you what this?

```
Public Function CasterTheGhost(Of S As IConvertible, T As IConvertible)(ByVal Source As T) As S
    Return Source.ToType(GetType(S), Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi,this seems to work indeed. Compiler warns me of an implicit cast, which surprises me... If I return CType(Source.ToType(GetType(S), Nothing), S) , will there be the T->S->Object->S or not? In terms of efficiency this counts.